# No network connect after installing ubuntu 22.04 on macbook

Tags: networking, drivers, macbook

I am new to ubuntu/Linux. I just installed 22.04 LTS on my macbook. Everything seems to work well except network. Here's what I see under Network section

[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCTyY.jpg)

Here's the output from lshw -c network.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff memory:8fa00000-8fa007ff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:a0500000-a0503fff
```

Looks like I already have driver for wifi. But after some research I have seen people say that I should install a different driver. I saw this post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471827/no-network-connect-after-installing-ubuntu-22-04-on-macbook). However, it does not seem to be my situation. I checked the currently loaded modules and it shows b43 is already used. Also, I don't have bcmwl-kernel-source installed.